# scaler variable not define

Tags: sql-server

I am getting `scalar variable not define @cmdSQL`
while trying to print my query to see what is d sql query is getting generating while running

```
print @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' from server_des where title Like ''%'+@title+'%'' AND Description  Like ''%'+@Description+'%'' AND Keywords Like ''%'+@Keywords+'%'' AND category Like ''%'+@Category+'%'' AND Location Like ''%'+@Location+'%''AND source Like ''%'+@Source+'%'' AND Date Like ''%'+@Date+'%'

exec All_Searchnew1 'man','thief','ma','ma','ma','ma','12/12/2009',1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0

procedure Is written below...


Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[All_Searchnew1]
@title nvarchar(max),
@Description nvarchar(max),
@Keywords nvarchar(max),
@Category nvarchar(max),
@Location nvarchar(max),
@Source nvarchar(max),
@Date nvarchar(50),
@RD_btn_AND_OR AS BIT,
@Chk_title AS BIT ,
@Chk_Description AS Bit ,
@Chk_Keywords AS BIT,
@Chk_Category AS BIT,
@Chk_Location AS BIT,
@Chk_Source AS BIT,
@Chk_Date AS BIT


AS

DECLARE @cmdSQL AS VARCHAR(2000) 
SET @cmdSQL = 'Select '

DECLARE @cmdCondition AS VARCHAR(2000) 
SET @cmdCondition = ''

if @RD_btn_AND_OR = 1
    Begin
    if (@Chk_title = 1)
          begin
          SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' title,'
          SET @cmdCondition ='title Like ''%' + @title + '%'''
          end
    else
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as title'
        SET @cmdCondition ='title Like ''%' + @title + '%'''
        end

    if  @Chk_Description <> 1
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Description,'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Description Like ''%' + @Description + '%'''
        end
    else
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as Description'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Description Like ''%' + @Description + '%'''
        end

    if  @Chk_Keywords <> 1
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Keywords,'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Keywords Like ''%' + @Keywords + '%'''
        end
    else
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as Keywords'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Keywords Like ''%' + @Keywords + '%'''
        end
    if  @Chk_Category <> 1
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Category,'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Category Like ''%' + @Category + '%'''
        end
    else
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as Category'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Category Like ''%' + @Category + '%'''
        end
    if  @Chk_Location <> 1
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Location,'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Location Like ''%' + @Location + '%'''
        end
    else
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as Location'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Location Like ''%' + @Location + '%'''
        end
    if  @Chk_Source <> 1 
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Source,'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Source Like ''%' + @Source + '%'''
        end
    else
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as Source'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Source Like ''%' + @Source + '%'''
        end
    if  @Chk_Date <> 1 
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' Date'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Date Like ''%' + @Date + '%'''
        end
    else
        begin
        SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as Date'
        SET @cmdCondition ='Date Like ''%' + @Date + '%'''
        end
End
--SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' from server_des where title like ''%''' + @title + '''%'' AND Description  Like '''%''+@Description+''%''' AND Keywords Like '''%''+@Keywords+''%''' AND category Like '''%''+@Category+''%''' AND Location Like '''%''+@Location+''%'''AND source Like '''%''+@Source+''%''' AND Date Like '''%''+@Date+''%''
--SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' from server_des where title Like ''%' + @title + '%''or description like ''%'+@Description+'%''or keywords like ''%'+@Keywords+'%''or category like ''%'+@Category+'%'''
SET @cmdCondition = @cmdCondition
SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ' from server_des where ' + @cmdCondition

EXEC(@cmdSQL)
go
```

Comment: can you fromat the code and put little code..its confusing...

Comment: You need to read up on the risks of SQL Injection - any parameter with an ' in, and you're in trouble

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight - If you were not able to understand the question and you do not know the answer. Do not give Points on question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you missed commas in expressions like this:
`SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as title'`
It should be `SET @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL +'null as title,'`

Missing something is common problem when combining dynamic SQL from many pieces. This work should be done very attentively.

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, you are running

```
print @cmdSQL = @cmdSQL + ...
```

before it's declared which is *only* in the stored procedure